# How do I add multiline text in a text box in MS Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

I am using MS Excel 365.

I cannot add line breaks or multi-line text in a text box of Excel file. When I press enter, the cursor switches to a different cell.

I want to add the line breaks or multi-line text in a text box. Can you please guide me how to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The button is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Hope it helps.